# Poisson's, Bernoulli's and Laplace's formulas

Tags: probability

I'm not sure if i got correct answers as i often choose q and p wrong

1. It is known that a team is equally likely to win three games out of five and
   two out of four. Find the probability of winning in one game.

**My attempt**: $$P_5(3)=P_4(2)$$ and using Bernoulli's formula I've got $$10p^3=6p^2$$ and answer p=0,6

2. The probability that the part will not pass the quality test is equal to 0.2. Which
   the probability that out of 400 randomly selected parts will be defective:

a) 80 parts;

b) from 30 to 80 parts

**My attempt:** p=0,2 q=0,8 n=400

A)k=80 $$P_{400}(80)=0,05$$ (Laplace's formulas)

B) $$P_{400}(30<=k<=80)=x(0)+x(6,25)=0,5$$

3. The probability of failure for each call is equal to 0.00008. Identify
   probability that at 1500 calls there will be 6 failures.

**My try:**

$$P_{1500}(6)=(0,12^6/6!)*exp(-0,12)=3,68*10^{-9}$$

Comment: All I can speak to is your use of Bernoulli's formula, in part 1.  I agree with your analysis.  By the way: +1 to your query, for good presentation + showing your work.

Answer (score 1):

1. ok
2. I do not know what do you mean with Laplace's formula.

Given that calculating the exact probability (with the calculator) it is $\approx 52.987\%$, using a gaussian approx I get

$$\mathbb{P}(30\leq k\leq 80)=\Phi\left( \frac{80.5-80}{8} \right)-\Phi\left( \frac{29.5-80}{8} \right)\approx 52.492\%$$

which is a better approximation of the actual value w.r.t. your 50%

3.Ok, the poisson is good for your purpose...